# SIMULINK If-Else flow block and its effect on Embedded Code Generation

Tags: function, matlab, code-generation, simulink

I wish to use an if-else flow block (or a custom matlab function that does it) in SIMULINK and use embedded coder to generate code for it. I had previously encountered a problem with zero and one-based indexing with MATLAB function blocks used in SIMULINK. It seems that there is practically no way around it. How can I model a if-elseif logic in SIMULINK then?

I have tried to use switch and mux blocks but they are too messy and could result into misinterpretation of original flow logic that I am trying to implement.

My flow logic (PSEUDOCODE) is:

```
if (a<b) then
    p = x;
else if (a<c) then
    p = max(y, some_const_val);
else
    p = z;
```

Could someone please suggest a way?

KR,

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudocode should work as a [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block (which supports code generation for the subset of MATLAB function). I can't really see any issues with zero and one-based indexing??

For more complicated logic, [Stateflow](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/stateflow/) is a very powerful tool, but then it's an add-on so you need to fork out more money if you don't already have it. I agree though that, apart for very simple logic algorithms, a purely Simulink=blocks approach can become very quickly cumbersome.

Comment: I already know about stateflow. The problem is that I don't want to subscribe for another few £1000 blockset without exploring all the option in basic MATLAB and SIMULINK distribution. Just to follow, up with your comment about "Can't see any issue with zero and one based indexing", did you actually generate Embedded Code (using Embedded Coder) for a MATLAB function block? Or did you turn some of the checks off when you use Code Generation Advisor that helps to overcome this problem? I would be very interested to know. Because it didn't work for me.

Comment: No, I haven't actually tried generating code (or if I did in the past, I didn't actually look that closely at what the code looked like, as long as it was functional). Could you explain what didn't work for you or what is the problem? Is it to with the fact that the generated C code uses one-based indexing instead of zero-based indexing?

Comment: Code Generation advisor always warns about the M-function blocks because of 1-based/0-based indexing. Obviously, I do not wish to keep any warning and get a full pass from Code Generation advisor. I have seen that you cannot pass a MATLAB function block through Code Generation advisor without a warning. There is no error! It is a warning! You can choose to ignore it but then your code generation will fail because you have not manage to clear all warnings and errors! However, you can set your model configuration parameters to ignore warnings, but then other important ones are being ignored!

Comment: It appears that the MATLAB Function block requires one-based indexing: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/82888. However, this should not affect the functionality of the code, only its efficiency. In fact the MAAB checks recommend that all blocks use one-based indexing, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/slvnv/ref/mathworks-automotive-advisory-board-checks.html#briw0kk-1